Let a user change role dynamically on the front end
I need to let users be able to change their role (or group) in order for them see a different menu and page contents via a front end form or dropdown list.
I am open to plugins and suggestions on how to accomplish this.
Is this something that's possible?
Thanks !

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
